# setAngularVelocity reduces in onGameResume, onPause

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I am setting a linear impulse on an object, it moves fine but when I press power button and then again come to game I noticed that my object rotation speed is lessened.

```
package com.algo;

import org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions.ScreenOrientation;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.RatioResolutionPolicy;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.primitive.Rectangle;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.Scene.IOnSceneTouchListener;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.background.ColorBackground;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.shape.Shape;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.sprite.AnimatedSprite;
import org.anddev.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsConnector;
import org.anddev.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsFactory;
import org.anddev.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsWorld;
import org.anddev.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.util.constants.PhysicsConstants;
import org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureOptions;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlas;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TiledTextureRegion;
import org.anddev.andengine.sensor.accelerometer.AccelerometerData;
import org.anddev.andengine.sensor.accelerometer.IAccelerometerListener;
import org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity;
import org.anddev.andengine.util.Debug;
import org.anddev.andengine.util.MathUtils;
import org.anddev.andengine.util.constants.TimeConstants;

import android.hardware.SensorManager;

import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.FixtureDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef.BodyType;

public class PhysicsTest1 extends BaseGameActivity implements IAccelerometerListener, IOnSceneTouchListener{

    private final float CAMERA_WIDTH = 800;
    private final float CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;

    private final float MAX_DISTANCE_FLING = 80f;
    private final float MAX_VELOCITY_CONST = 250f;
    private final float DEFAULT_VELOCITY = 50f;

    private BitmapTextureAtlas mBitmapTextureAtlas;

    private Scene mScene;

    protected TiledTextureRegion mBoxFaceTextureRegion;
    protected TiledTextureRegion mCircleFaceTextureRegion;

    protected PhysicsWorld mPhysicsWorld;

    private int mFaceCount = 0;


    private float X = 0;
    private float Y = 0;

    private Body body =  null;  

    @Override
    public void onLoadComplete() {


    }

    @Override
    public Engine onLoadEngine() {      
        final Camera camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
        final EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera);
        engineOptions.getTouchOptions().setRunOnUpdateThread(true);
        return new Engine(engineOptions);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadResources() {

        this.mBitmapTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(64, 64, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
        BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
        this.mBoxFaceTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "face_box_tiled.png", 0, 0, 2, 1); // 64x32
        this.mCircleFaceTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "face_circle_tiled.png", 0, 32, 2, 1); // 64x32
        this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas);
    }

    @Override
    public Scene onLoadScene() {


        this.mScene = new Scene();
        this.mScene.setBackground(new ColorBackground(0, 0, 0));
        this.mScene.setOnSceneTouchListener(this);
        this.mScene.setOnSceneTouchListenerBindingEnabled(true);

        this.mPhysicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0, SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH), false);

        final Shape ground = new Rectangle(0, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 2, CAMERA_WIDTH, 2);
        final Shape roof = new Rectangle(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, 2);
        final Shape left = new Rectangle(0, 0, 2, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
        final Shape right = new Rectangle(CAMERA_WIDTH - 2, 0, 2, CAMERA_HEIGHT);

        final FixtureDef wallFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0.5f, 0.3f);
        PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, ground, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
        PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, roof, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
        PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, left, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
        PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, right, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);

        this.mScene.attachChild(ground);
        this.mScene.attachChild(roof);
        this.mScene.attachChild(left);
        this.mScene.attachChild(right);

        this.mScene.registerUpdateHandler(this.mPhysicsWorld);

        addFace(0,0);

        return this.mScene;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResumeGame() {
        super.onResumeGame();

        this.enableAccelerometerSensor(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPauseGame() {
        super.onPauseGame();

        this.disableAccelerometerSensor();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccelerometerChanged(AccelerometerData pAccelerometerData) {
//      final Vector2 gravity = Vector2Pool.obtain(pAccelerometerData.getX(), pAccelerometerData.getY());
//      this.mPhysicsWorld.setGravity(gravity);
//      Vector2Pool.recycle(gravity);

    }

    private float Xlocal = 0.0f;
    private float Ylocal = 0.0f;
    private long timeDown = 0;

    @Override
    public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
//      if(this.mPhysicsWorld != null) {
//          if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
//              this.addFace(pSceneTouchEvent.getX(), pSceneTouchEvent.getY());
//              return true;
//          }       

        if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
            timeDown = System.currentTimeMillis();

            System.out.println("Time down is "+timeDown);

            Xlocal = pSceneTouchEvent.getX();
            Ylocal = pSceneTouchEvent.getY();           
        } else if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()) {

            X = (pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - Xlocal);
            Y = (pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - Ylocal);

            float distance = getDistance(Xlocal, Ylocal, pSceneTouchEvent.getX(), pSceneTouchEvent.getY());
            if( distance >= MAX_DISTANCE_FLING){
                long timeUp = System.currentTimeMillis();

                System.out.println("Time up is "+timeUp);

                shootBall(X, Y, distance, (float) (timeUp - timeDown) / TimeConstants.MILLISECONDSPERSECOND);
            }           
        }


//      }
        return true;        
    }


    private void addFace(final float pX, final float pY) {
        this.mFaceCount++;
        Debug.d("Faces: " + this.mFaceCount);

        final AnimatedSprite face;


        final FixtureDef objectFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0.3f, 0.2f, 0.3f);
        final FixtureDef objectFixtureDefKinetic = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0.5f, 0.4f, 0f);

//      if(this.mFaceCount % 2 == 0) {

            face = new AnimatedSprite(pX, pY, this.mCircleFaceTextureRegion){
                @Override
                public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {

//                  if(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
//                      Xlocal = pSceneTouchEvent.getX();
//                      Ylocal = pSceneTouchEvent.getY();
//                      
//                  }else if(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_UP){
//                      float x = pSceneTouchEvent.getX();
//                      float y = pSceneTouchEvent.getY();
//                      
//                      x = Math.abs(x - Xlocal);
//                      y = Math.abs(y - Ylocal);
//                      
//                      shootBall(x, y);
//                  }
//                      
//                  return mVisible;
                    return false;
                }           
            };
            face.setScale(2);


            AnimatedSprite face2 = new AnimatedSprite((CAMERA_WIDTH * 0.5f) - mBoxFaceTextureRegion.getWidth(), (CAMERA_HEIGHT * 0.5f) - mBoxFaceTextureRegion.getHeight(), this.mBoxFaceTextureRegion.clone());
            Body bodyKinetic = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, face2, BodyType.KinematicBody, objectFixtureDefKinetic);            
            bodyKinetic.setAngularVelocity(15f);

            AnimatedSprite face3 = new AnimatedSprite(400f, 100f, this.mBoxFaceTextureRegion.clone());
            Body body2 = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, face3, BodyType.DynamicBody, objectFixtureDef);           
            body2.setLinearDamping(2f);
            body2.setAngularDamping(10f);           


//      } else {
//          face = new AnimatedSprite(pX, pY, this.mBoxFaceTextureRegion);
//          face.setScale(MathUtils.random(0.5f, 1.25f));
//          body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, face, BodyType.DynamicBody, objectFixtureDef);
//      }   

        body = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, face, BodyType.DynamicBody, objectFixtureDef);       
        body.setBullet(true);
        this.mScene.attachChild(face);
        this.mScene.registerTouchArea(face);
        this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(face, body, true, true));

        this.mScene.attachChild(face2);
        this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(face2, bodyKinetic));

        this.mScene.attachChild(face3);
        this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(face3, body2));
    }


    private void shootBall(final float pX, final float pY, final float pDistance, final float pTime) {

        System.out.println("Time Final seconds "+pTime);

        float angleRad =(float)Math.atan2(pY, pX);
        float velocity = this.getVelocity(pTime);//(pDistance * 12.5f) / 100f;      
        if(body != null){           
            float Vx = velocity * (float)Math.cos(angleRad);
            float Vy = velocity * (float)Math.sin(angleRad);
            body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(Vx,Vy), body.getWorldCenter()); 
            body.setAngularDamping(0.8f); //to decrease velocity slowly. no linear no floaty :)
            body.setLinearDamping(0.5f);
            body.applyTorque(100f);
        }
    }

    private float getDistance(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2){
        float X2_ = (float)Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2);
        float Y2_ = (float)Math.pow(y2 -  y1, 2);       

        float distance = (float)Math.sqrt(X2_ + Y2_);       
        return distance;
    }

    private float getVelocity(float pTime) {
        float velocity = MAX_VELOCITY_CONST - (pTime * 100f);
        if (velocity < DEFAULT_VELOCITY) {
            velocity = DEFAULT_VELOCITY;
        }
        System.out.println("velocity  "+velocity);
        return velocity;
    }

}
```

**please see bodyKinetic.setAngularVelocity(15f);**

**Update**

@Override
    public void onResumeGame() {
        super.onResumeGame();

```
    if(bodyKinetic != null){
        System.out.println("set angular veclocity resume ");
        bodyKinetic.setAngularVelocity(25f);
    }       
    this.enableAccelerometerSensor(this);
}
```

Its strange that when I run it in dubug mode it runs ok and without debug it has no effect

**Update**
I have also unreg and re-reg body but still of no use :(

```
@Override
    public void onResumeGame() {
        super.onResumeGame();       

        if(bodyKinetic != null){
            System.out.println("OnResumeGame Angular Velocity "+bodyKinetic.getAngularVelocity());

            this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector((IShape) bodyKinetic.getUserData(), bodyKinetic));
            bodyKinetic.setAngularVelocity(25f);    
        }

        this.enableAccelerometerSensor(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPauseGame() {
        super.onPauseGame();
        if(bodyKinetic != null){
            System.out.println("OnPauseGame Angular Velocity "+bodyKinetic.getAngularVelocity());
        bodyKinetic.setAngularVelocity(0f);
            this.mPhysicsWorld.unregisterPhysicsConnector(this.mPhysicsWorld.getPhysicsConnectorManager().findPhysicsConnectorByShape((IShape) bodyKinetic.getUserData()));
        }       

        this.disableAccelerometerSensor();
    }
```

Comment: bodyKinetic.applyAngularImpulse(25f) have no effect over body, why?

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using DynamicBody? Kinematic bodies are for special purposes and not relevant in most cases.

Comment: Yes because I am using my body as a rotational panel. That should not move but only rotate. It is my game logic.

Comment: According to the Box2D manual, Kinematic bodies do not respond to forces and behave as if they had infinite mass. That's why applying angular or linear impulse has no effect.

Comment: no this is not correct. It also states that you can move them by setting velocity over them. Angular velocity is not applied at the center of body so it moves body in circular motion and the problem is not that body is not moving.. rather it reduces speed on each onPause( ) call

Comment: Yes, you can **set** the velocity, but applying an impulse will have no effect. That is why bodyKinetic.applyAngularImpulse(25f) has no effect. I should have made myself more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try saving the bodies' velocities in onPauseGame() and setting them back in onResume(). You can also try setting linear and angular damping to 0 when pausing the game and reseting the values when resuming. The damping sometimes behaved weirdly in the project I work on.

The fact that you're experiencing a heisenbug suggests that it might be a bug in the engine.

Comment: I am using UpdateHandler to fix it

Comment: I have also done what you said even I un-reg and re-reg in onResume but of no use :(

Comment: I have one more convoluted idea - if Dynamic bodies behave correctly, you can change the body type to dynamic on pause and on resume set back the correct position and velocities and change the body type to kinematic. Have you asked on the AndEngine forums? Maybe it's just some stupid oversight on our part.

Comment: Yes I have asked on andEngine site and also reported as a bug. I am now setting angular velocity in updateHandler and after getting called say 2 or 3 times velocity is set. Link#1 http://www.andengine.org/forums/bugs/setangularvelocity-slows-down-in-onpausegame-t6999.html   Link#2: http://www.andengine.org/forums/post30714.html#p30714